# Does Tree Tubing still work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to [tube](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Trivia) some trees, to force them to grow large. I planted my sapling in a 1x1x2 hole, but this happened:

[image]

Was tree tubing nerfed at some point?

Comment: Do not know for sure but that may have gone the way of the dodo when the code was added that let trees grow right next to each other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, I've done some research of my own, and the following seems to be the case:

### Tree tubing *does* work, but not with dirt

Using dirt tubes of height 2 and 3, normal trees still grow:
[image]

*However*, using cobblestone tubes, large trees *always* grow:
[image]